# Finding centroid of cluster of points using R

Tags: r, centroids

While searching the web, solutions for finding centroids of polygons come up rather often. What I'm interested in is finding a centroid of a cluster of points. A weighted mean of sorts.

Can you provide some pointers, pseudo code (or even better, an R package that has already solved this) or links of how this issue can be tackled?

---

@iant has suggested a method to average coordinates and use that for the centroid. This is exactly what crossed my mind when I saw the right picture on [this web page](http://number-none.com/product/My%20Friend,%20the%20Covariance%20Body/index.html).

Here is some simple R code to draw the following figure that demonstrates this (× is the centroid):

```
xcor <- rchisq(10, 3, 2)
ycor <- runif(10, min = 1, max = 100)
mx <- mean(xcor)
my <- mean(ycor)

plot(xcor, ycor, pch = 1)
points(mx, my, pch = 3)
```

[image]

---

`cluster::pam()$medoids` returns a medoid of a set of cluster. This is an example from @Joris Meys:

```
library(cluster)
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(100, 0), Y = rpois(100, 2))
plot(df$X, df$Y)
points(pam(df, 1)$medoids, pch = 16, col = "red")
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

just average the X and Y coordinates (multiply by  a weight if you want) and there is your centroid.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the centroid of a cluster of points in R, you can use simple statistical methods to find the mean of the x and y coordinates. This approach is effective for an unweighted centroid. If you're looking for a weighted centroid, you'll need to factor in the weights of each point in your calculations.

Here's a basic method to find the unweighted centroid:

```
# Sample data
xcor <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ycor <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

# Calculating the centroid
centroid_x <- mean(xcor)
centroid_y <- mean(ycor)

print(paste("Centroid:", centroid_x, centroid_y))
```

For a weighted centroid, you would modify the calculation to account for the weights:

```
# Sample data with weights
xcor <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ycor <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
weights <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)  # Example weights

# Weighted centroid calculation
weighted_centroid_x <- sum(xcor * weights) / sum(weights)
weighted_centroid_y <- sum(ycor * weights) / sum(weights)

print(paste("Weighted Centroid:", weighted_centroid_x, weighted_centroid_y))
```

Additional R Package:
For more advanced calculations or handling of spatial data, you might consider using the geosphere package which provides a centroid function. This can be particularly useful for geographic data.

```
library(geosphere)
# Assuming 'points' is a matrix or dataframe of your coordinates
centroid <- centroid(points)
```

Online Tool for Quick Calculations:
As an additional resource, you can use the [**online Centroid Calculator**](https://webtoolapps.com/centroid-calculator/). This tool provides a simple interface for calculating the centroid of a set of points, which can be handy for quick checks or when working outside of R.

Answer (score -1):

This is excellent. I'd suggest removing outliers before doing this. For simple outlier removal, one might find the longitudes within the 75%-25% percentiles and the same for the latitudes, and only calculate mean on those values? Or for less drastic outlier removal, remove values outside the 1.5 * 75%-25% interquartile range (this is a somewhat standard outlier definition).